# Como habilitar a tecla TAB no Emacs

Tags: linux, editor-de-texto

Uso *Debian Linux* **7** e estou fazendo um teste com o editor **Emacs** pra edição de códigos. Já fiz várias personalizações no arquivo `.emacs` mas não consigo fazer a tecla TAB funcionar para fazer a indentação dos códigos. Quando pressiono a tecla TAB no emacs, simplesmente não acontece nada.

Alguém pode me dar alguma pista sobre como habilitar a tecla TAB no Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a documentação http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~rlr/Misc/emacs_tabs.htm#one_thing

edite o seu arquivo .emacs e adicione isso:

```
# Tab em todos modos de edicao    
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command);
```